# Rocketchat oauth parameters

Tags: oauth, rocket.chat

Im integrating rocketchat in a project and in order to perform the login using oauth the API require two parameters:

credentialToken and credentialSecret,

This is the snippet they give on the documentation:

```
{
    "msg": "method",
    "method": "login",
    "id":"42",
    "params": [
        {
            "oauth": {
                "credentialToken":"credential-token",
                "credentialSecret":"credential-secret"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The question is: Where do I get those? Im not even sure what is each one because using their registration system only return a random userId, so I don't have the token neither the "secret".

I'm using the realtime API by the way.

Thanks in advance.